# Is infinite union of RE a RE?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, automata

Is an infinite set of RE languages create a language that is also RE?

I think it's true, and my first intuition is to try induction to prove this statement.

Am I on the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Any language $L$ is the (countably infinite) union of all singleton languages which contain just one word of $L$.

Comment: @Watercrystal Why don't you post an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted?

Comment: Sure, I'll expand a bit then.

Comment: Infinite union is a powerful concept because *every* language is an infinite (countable) union of singletons, as noted in the answer. A natural question on each "language level": 
-- [Infinite ...Union of regular languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67316/4287)
-- [Is an inﬁnite union of context-free languages always context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/206/4287)
-- [Complexity classes closed under finite union ..., why not infinite union...?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124914/4287)
-- [Infinite union of recursive languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17938/4287)

Answer (score 4):

The statement is not true; any language $L$ can be written as the (countably infinite) union of singleton languages which each just contain one word of $L$.

Also, even if the statement was true, one could not prove it using (regular) induction. This is because the *finite* union of RE languages is indeed RE. My go-to example here is that one can show using induction that every natural number is finite, but there exists no infinite natural number.

Comment: I don't see why it is a counter-example.  Let me write it formally: If $L_1,L_2,...$ is an infinite set of languages such that each one of them is in RE, then $\bigcup_{j=1,2,...}L_j$ is in RE.

Comment: @Geo His answer is a counter-example. Consider $L$ a non-RE language. Since any language is countable, you can count its words, $u_1, u_2, …$ Now $L = \bigcup\limits_{j\geqslant 0}\{u_j\}$, and each $\{u_j\}$ is RE (because it is finite).

Comment: @Nathaniel i do not understand, L is RE, why assuming its not?

Comment: We show that a non-RE language can be written as the countably infinite union of RE languages. That shows that in general, such infinite unions of RE languages are not necessarily RE themselves.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but say you have a non-RE language $L$, how are you going to take its singleton elements and then build $L$ back if there is no TM that can tell if $w$ is in $L$. How do we even know that $w$ is even in $L$?

Comment: @Russel There exists non-RE languages. Let $L$ be such a language. $L$ is countable (that's a fact), so let $u_1$, $u_2$, … be an enumeration of its words (such an enumeration exists, though it is not computable because $L$ is not RE, but that's not a problem here). For any $j\geqslant 0$, the language $L_j = \{u_j\}$ is RE (it is even regular, since $L_j$ is finite). But by definition, $L = \bigcup\limits_{j\geqslant 0} L_j$. We proved the existence of a non-RE language that is an infinite union of RE languages.

Comment: @Nathaniel, I do understand that non-RE languages exists. I just cannot grasp the idea that we are like constructing a language "out of thin air", since we do not even know what strings we are using in the construction in the first place. We do not even know whether such non-RE languages are non-empty (I think?).

Comment: Any finite language is regular, hence recursive, hence RE, so a non-RE language is necessarily infinite… You do not need to know a constructive method for such a language (and it does not exist by definition of a non-RE language), just that such a language exists. For example, consider $L_e = \{\langle M \rangle \mid L(M) = \emptyset\}$ (which is a well known non-RE language).