# Is the infinite union of decidable languages decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, decidability, recursively-enumerable

I am currently struggling with figuring out the following problem:

Given decidable languages L1, L2, L3, L4, ...

Is the infinite union of Languages L1, ...... decidable? I have an intution that it is not, but I cannot find an example against that thesis.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Infinite union is a powerful concept because every language is an infinite union of singletons, as noted in the answer. This question has been asked on each "language level": 
-- [Infinite ...Union of regular languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67316/4287) 
-- [Is an inﬁnite union of context-free languages always context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/206/4287) 
-- [Complexity classes closed under finite union ..., why not infinite union...?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124914/4287) 
-- [Infinite union of recursive languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17938/4287)

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is right.

Hint: for any $x$, the language $\{x\}$ is decidable. Think how we can use this fact to construct an undecidable language.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still leaving me clueless. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You agree that $\{x\}$ is decidable for any singleton?  Now, take any undecidable set.  What's that but a countable union of singletons?